# Proper way to define function in Controller as vm

Tags: angularjs

In html I have this:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController as vm">

    <h1>{{vm.message}}</h1> 

    {{vm.username}}

    <form name="searchUser">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Find username" ng-model="vm.username">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="vm.search()">
        //or should it be without vm.?
        //<input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search()">
    </form>

    <h4>{{vm.error}}</h4>

    <h3>{{vm.user.name}}</h3>
    <img ng-src="{{vm.user.avatar_url}}" title="{{vm.user.name}}">

</div>
```

Here are some variations - which one is the recommended?

Option 1:

```
(function() {

    function MainController($http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = 'GitHub Viewer';
        vm.username = 'angular';

        vm.successCallback = function (response){
            vm.user = response.data;
        }

        vm.errorCallback = function (response){
            vm.error = 'Could not fetch the user data';
        }

        vm.search = function(){
            $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + vm.username)
                .then(vm.successCallback, vm.errorCallback);            
        }

        vm.search();

    }

    angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

})();
```

Option 2:

```
(function() {

    function MainController($http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = 'GitHub Viewer';
        vm.username = 'angular';

        var successCallback = function (response){
            vm.user = response.data;
        }

        var errorCallback = function (response){
            vm.error = 'Could not fetch the user data';
        }

        var search = function(){
            $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + vm.username)
                .then(successCallback, errorCallback);            
        }

        search();

    }

    angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

})();
```

Option 3:

```
(function() {

    function MainController($http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = 'GitHub Viewer';
        vm.username = 'angular';

        function successCallback (response){
            vm.user = response.data;
        }

        function errorCallback (response){
            vm.error = 'Could not fetch the user data';
        }

        function search(){
            $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + vm.username)
                .then(successCallback, errorCallback);            
        }

        search();

    }

    angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);

})();
```

Comment: I suggest  you the 2 and  3 options (they  are pratically similar).

Comment: try adding `return vm` at the end of your functions. It used to be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using 'controller as' syntax you can't simply call any function that's in the controller. Functions not assigned to vm will not be visible from the view and therefore cannot be called.

The success and error callback functions don't have to be assigned to vm as they are only called internally by the promise.

I personally don't like assigning internal function to local variables. Doing that makes it impossible to reference them before they are defined.

Here's how I would write the controller:

```
(function() {

    MainController.$inject = ['$http'];

    function MainController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.message = 'GitHub Viewer';
        vm.username = 'angular';
        vm.search = search;
        vm.user = null;
        vm.error = null;

        search();

        function search () {
            $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + vm.username)
                .then(successCallback, errorCallback);            
        }

        function successCallback (response) {
            vm.user = response.data;
        }

        function errorCallback (response) {
            vm.error = 'Could not fetch the user data';
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

With `vm.search(...)` is right;
Then [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) is more appropriate than `ng-click`

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController as vm">

<h1>{{vm.message}}</h1> 

{{vm.username}}

<form name="searchUser">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Find username" ng-model="vm.username">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-change="vm.search()">
</form>

<h4>{{vm.error}}</h4>

<h3>{{vm.user.name}}</h3>
<img ng-src="{{vm.user.avatar_url}}" title="{{vm.user.name}}">
```